# horizontal list word wrap

Tags: html, css, list, word-wrap

So I have a ol with 4 itmes. When there isn't enough room to display all of them I want it to wrap to the next line but only on the center of the list

So i have

```
<ol>
<li>A</li>
<li>B</li>
<li>C</li>
<li>D</li>
</ol>
```

and it displays like so,

```
A B C D
```

However when I shrink the page I want it to display like

```
A B
C D
```

instead of

```
A B C
D
```

So i need to put something between BC but I don't know what.
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You can write markup like this:

**HTML**

```
<ol>
 <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
 </ul>    
</ol>
```

**CSS**

```
ol li{
    width:150px;
    background:red;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}
ul{
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/nkAtV/1/

Comment: This is a bit useless. How do you know where to split the ULs? What is the words are longer? How wide is the page?